# Play a certain sound from a /playsound value

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If I run this command:

```
/playsound ambient.cave master @a ~ ~ ~ 1
```

It plays a cave sound, but when I run it again, it plays a different cave sound.

On the wiki, it says there are 18 different cave sounds for that one command, so I've tried to do something like this:

```
/playsound ambient.cave1 master @a ~ ~ ~ 1
```

But nothing plays.

Is there a way to play a certain cave sound (or any sound value with multiple sounds) every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to most sources I could find on the internet, you can not play a specific variation of the sound every time.  The sound variation is randomly chosen by the client when the command is executed.

Comment: For what it's worth [I asked on Reddit on Dinnerbone's 1.13 changes post](https://www.reddit.com/r/u_Dinnerbone/comments/6l6e3d/comment/dky0j3v) since they're completely redoing the command system.

Comment: @CAD97 I will be keeping an eye on that, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can, you just have to add a little more to a resource pack. All you have to do is add to your sounds.json

```
"rw.music.nss":{"sounds":[{"name":"**music/game/nether/nether1**","stream":true}],"category":"master"}
```

You can have the first text whatever, it is what you use to call the sound.

Now you must find the sound/music you want to play, and describe where it is located in the bolded area.

Answer (score 0):

As @IronAnvil stated, you cant play one of the x sounds defined for cave; it is designated randomly. What you may do is duplicate it in a ressource pack and playing it.

Answer (score -2):

you can try the same as getting different wool colors or different mobs spawns.

it should be something like:

```
/playsound ambient.cave master @a ~ ~ ~ 1:1
```

Or

```
/playsound ambient.cave master @a ~ ~ ~ 1 1
```

I haven't tried it... I hope it works.

Comment: the syntax is `/playsound (sound) (source) (player) [x] [y] [z] [volume] [pitch] [minimumvolume]` so the second one would be pitch. good idea tho

Comment: @Tomenos Mauserrio  The person who asked the question is correcting your answer.  Pointing out why it won't work.  Please don't post answers that you are unsure if they work.  You posted a guess.

Comment: that can't be 1:1 or 1 1. the first 1 is the volume and the second 1 is the pitch, after it you can put the minimumVolume